# amchart dateAxis labels position on zooming

Tags: position, amcharts, axis-labels

How I can stop wrong behavior of labels of dateAxis on zooming?
For example, there is a chart with date labels under line of grid. If we change horizontal zoom to half, the labels under center of column (between grid's lines).

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/xy-chart-date-based-axis/

[Screenshot of chart without zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGKoT.png)

[Screenshot of chart with zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9EIg.png)

I think it depends from grid mode, but can't find options that responsible for the labels position on other grid mode.

Comment: It's by design: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#_location_and_DateAxis

Comment: thank you! A solution was simple: dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.0001;